# Unable to access CakePHP email view variables

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I'm trying to set variables for an HTML email template, but I can't seem to be able to access the variables. When I echo the variable name in the template, in the sent email it shows an error saying "undefined variable". In the error description, it even shows the variables that were set.

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('info@example.com' => 'Test'));
$Email->to('myemail@email.com');
$Email->subject('Test email variables');
$Email->template('layout_1'); 
$Email->emailFormat('html');
$Email->viewVars(array('input_1','test input 1'));
$Email->send();
```

The following error shows up in the email and I can actually see the "input 1" variable that I set.

```
    NOTICE (8): UNDEFINED VARIABLE: INPUT_1 [APP/VIEW/EMAILS/HTML/LAYOUT_1.CTP, LINE 44]
CODE CONTEXT

                            <TR>
                                <TD CLASS="HEADER-BAR" VALIGN="TOP" STYLE="COLOR: #999; FONT-FAMILY: VERDANA; FONT-SIZE: 10PX; TEXT-TRANSFORM: UPPERCASE; PADDING: 0 20PX; HEIGHT: 15PX;" WIDTH="400" 
HEIGHT="15">
                                    <?PHP PRINT_R($INPUT_1); ?>
$VIEWFILE = '/APPLICATIONS/XAMPP/XAMPPFILES/HTDOCS/APP/VIEW/EMAILS/HTML/LAYOUT_1.CTP'
$DATAFORVIEW = ARRAY(
    'CONTENT' => '',
    (INT) 0 => 'INPUT_1',
    (INT) 1 => 'TEST INPUT 1'
)
$CONTENT = ''
INCLUDE - APP/VIEW/EMAILS/HTML/LAYOUT_1.CTP, LINE 44
VIEW::_EVALUATE() - CORE/CAKE/VIEW/VIEW.PHP, LINE 945
VIEW::_RENDER() - CORE/CAKE/VIEW/VIEW.PHP, LINE 907
VIEW::RENDER() - CORE/CAKE/VIEW/VIEW.PHP, LINE 471
CAKEEMAIL::_RENDERTEMPLATES() - CORE/CAKE/NETWORK/EMAIL/CAKEEMAIL.PHP, LINE 1582
CAKEEMAIL::_RENDER() - CORE/CAKE/NETWORK/EMAIL/CAKEEMAIL.PHP, LINE 1448
CAKEEMAIL::SEND() - CORE/CAKE/NETWORK/EMAIL/
CAKEEMAIL.PHP, LINE 1073
TEMPLATESCONTROLLER::SEND_NEWSLETTER() - APP/CONTROLLER/TEMPLATESCONTROLLER.PHP, LINE 110
TEMPLATESCONTROLLER::EDIT() - APP/CONTROLLER/TEMPLATESCONTROLLER.PHP, LINE 194
REFLECTIONMETHOD::INVOKEARGS() - [INTERNAL], LINE ??
CONTROLLER::INVOKEACTION() - CORE/CAKE/CONTROLLER/CONTROLLER.PHP, LINE 486
DISPATCHER::_INVOKE() - CORE/CAKE/ROUTING/DISPATCHER.PHP, LINE 187
DISPATCHER::DISPATCH() - CORE/CAKE/ROUTING/DISPATCHER.PHP, LINE 162
[MAIN] - APP/WEBROOT/INDEX.PHP, LINE 111
```

I also tried to print that $dataforview variable that shows, but I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used cake in ages, but quickly looking at their docs they are expecting a key => value array passed to viewVars() method.

I assume you meant to do:
`$Email->viewVars(array('input_1' => 'test input 1'));`

Secondly, it looks like are you are defining the value as "input_1", but trying to access it as "INPUT_1". In PHP, variables are case sensitive.

Comment: We've all been here :P